# Tableau Auto-refresh local on-premises Database/files on Mac

Tags: tableau-api

I wonder anyone has succeeded in refreshed publishing workbook from local on-premises database/files on Mac?   I am using Tableau Online and I made Tabcmd working on mac. But seems I need Tableau Data Extract Command-line Utility to do the job.

I do not want to use VMs or Windows machines as it may cause trouble for my database management, which I built with OS X.  I also tried Wine/Crossover to run Tableau.exe on Mac, which did not work.

Any better suggestions?  Please kindly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

If you want to create a Tableau data extract programmatically, you can write a script or program that calls the Tableau Data Extract API.

If you want to upload something to Tableau server, you can write a script or program that calls the Tableau REST API

Comment: Thank you fore your reply, Alex. I have already created those extracts and published datasources and workbooks to Tableau Online.  The database in our company updates everyday, so what I am trying to do is to 'refresh' the published workbooks with the changes in our database, and I want to do this programmatically on Mac. Tableau's official solution is using Tableau Data Extract Command-line Utility to 'Refresh an extract' of the on premise data source. Because published workbook will be based on the published data extract, this will automatically refresh the data in the published workbook.

Comment: However, Tableau Data Extract Command-line Utility or Tableau Sync Client are only available on Windows. I am trying to achieve the 'auto-refresh' goal on Mac by other methods, without using a Virtual Machine or Parallel. Thanks!

Comment: The API is available on macs even though the command line utility is not. It is part of the Tableau SDK. So you can write your own script to generate extracts. The command line utility is principally just a wrapper around the API. The Rest API for publishing to the server can be called from any platform that can speak HTTP.

Comment: If you want to encourage Tableau to make the Data Extract command line utility available for mac, then upvote the following ideas https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4671 and https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4670

Comment: Thanks Alex!  I am emailing Tableau to ask if Tableau SDK is an alternative, and for sure I hope Tableau can do as many on Mac as on Windows.  Thanks again.